# Loading images dynamically and attach onload event listner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button to load images. When user clicks on it, it needs to bring back 6 images initially with an option to load more images. I am dynamically creating  and other necessary tags. I want to set onload event to every  tag. This is what I have so far.

```
image = getImageElement(100,150);
image.id = "imageId" + cIds[i] + "";
image.name = "imageId" + cIds[i] + "";
image.onload = function (){ alert('Hello');};
```

But this function is not being called. Eventually, this function would be responsible to bring back the actual image. and each image block would be loaded dynamically and independently.

We are using all sorts of javascript technology from plain JS to jQuery and DWR. So solution using any flavor of javascript is fine.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you register any network activity? Chrome's developer tools for example would show something in its "Network" tab. Also, what does `getImageElement()` do?

Comment: @Derija93

Sorry could not format the code. But it is below.

function getImageElement(width,height){
 
      var image = document.createElement('img');
  
      if(width != null){
       image.width = width;
      }
  
      if(height != null){
   image.height = height;
      }
  
      return image;
 
     }

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **image object**. How you account for six images was not described in your question.

```
img = new Image();
img.id = "imageId" + cIds[i] + "";
img.name = "imageId" + cIds[i] + "";
img.onload = function (){ alert('Hello');};
img.src = "...some url...";
```

Comment: I have using createElement method. and I prepare the <Table> structure first and create other elements like <Img> dynamically and I want to attach onload event once the image tag created and call the function to fetch actual image and set it to this image tag.

Comment: There are lazy-load scripts available for jQuery. You might want to give that a try.